# Iterate trought keyframes of a spline's bevel_factor_start

Tags: python, animation, blender, spline

How can I iterate trought all the keyframes in a spline's `bevel_factor_start`?
I have the following code:

```
o = bpy.context.object
curve = o.data.bevel_factor_start.animation_data.action.fcurves
start = fcurve.find('bevel_factor_start')

for k in start:

    actual = k.co[1]
    print(actual)
```

But it doesn't work, any way to do it?

Comment: what is `o`? Mind adding some code?

Comment: oh, forgot it, adding it.